# Difference between >&/dev/null and &>/dev/null

Tags: shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors

I tried to find information about the operator order in the statement

```
>&/dev/null
```

Is there any difference between `>&` and `&>`?

Comment: @Freddy *in bash*, there's no difference between `>&/dev/null` and `&>/dev/null`, but there's a hell of a difference between `>&path` and `>&number` (as the OP's `>&/dev/null` and the `>&2` you point to). You can find better duplicates by searching for `&gt;&amp;` with meta.stackexchange.com queries.

Comment: data.stackexchange.com queries, sorry ;-)

Comment: @UncleBilly Yes, you're right, I removed my close vote. Maybe someone else finds a better duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual [3.6.4 Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> 3.6.4 Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error
>
> This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and
> the standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be redirected to the
> file whose name is the expansion of word.
>
> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard
> error:
>
> ```
> &>word
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> >&word
> ```
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred. This is semantically
> equivalent to
>
> ```
> >word 2>&1
> ```
>
> When using the second form, word may not expand to a number or ‘-’. If
> it does, other redirection operators apply (see Duplicating File
> Descriptors below) for compatibility reasons.